# Qual o custo de uso da API Google Maps para criar rotas?

Tags: ios, api, google-maps

Estou criando um app onde pego a atual posição do usuário e criaria uma rota para um determinado ponto. 
 Um amigo comentou que este serviço de rotas oferecido pela Google é pago.
 Alguem poderia ou saberia informar com mais detalhes sobre estes valores ?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a API free de Google Maps é apenas para app públicos com limites de 2500 requisições de webservices e 25 pageviews.

Para qualquer aplicação interna a Google entende que está em produção, portanto, deverá contratar a licença mesmo que esteja dentro dos limites da Free.

Recomendo para os desenvolvedores o alinhamento com os TOS(term os services) pois o Compliance Google uma hora acaba cobrando, e ja vi muitas aplicações serem cortadas além de terem que pagar o que foi utilizado ilegal.

recomendo para aquisição da API a empresa MAPLINK  http://maplinkbusiness.com/

Pois para mim Foi a única que soube esclarecer todas questões técnicas e não apenas forçar uma venda de API. Além de ser a maior parceira de Google MAps na América latina e com isso praticar melhores preços. Qual outra revenda é apenas uma revendas de meia duzia de vendedores querendo se dar bem

Comment: Carlos sua resposta foi muito boa!! Obrigado

Answer (score 8):

Existe uma versão grátis da API.

[Segundo a documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en-us#Limits), as diferenças da versão grátis e da paga são as seguintes:

**Usuários da API gratuita:**

- 2.500 solicitações de rotas por dia.
- Até 8 pontos de referência em cada solicitação. Pontos de referência não estão disponíveis para rotas com transporte público.
- 2 solicitações por segundo.

**Usuários do Google Maps API para empresas:**

- 100.000 solicitações de rotas por dia.
- Até 23 pontos de referência em cada solicitação. Pontos de referência não estão disponíveis para rotas com transporte público.
- 10 solicitações por segundo.

Quanto à questão do preço, acredito que você tenha que [entrar em contato](https://www.google.com/work/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html?hl=en&rd=1#display=cs-dialog-form) com eles para fazer uma cotação.

Answer (score 2):

O valor padrão deles é 15 mil dólares/ano.

### Edit

O Google mudou este ano sua política de preços, e todos podem desfrutar da mesma tabela: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/?hl=pt-BR

A boa notícia é que todos ganham 200 dólares grátis mensais, o que deve contemplar muitos projetos pequenos.

Comment: A pergunta é: pra que precisamos de um cartão de crédito, se muitos projetos pequenos não vão gastar? Por que não ter uma opção de cortar o serviço após a quota grátis? Não fica parecendo que eles vão cobrar de qualquer forma depois de um tempo, e será uma dor de cabeça para (tentarmos) cancelar o que (achávamos que) não concordamos em pagar? Ou alguém aqui lê todas aquelas letras miúdas?

Answer (score 1):

Se pretendes apenas usar a API da google maps na tua app então não tens de pagar nada.

Mais informações:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq

Comment: Sim so o mapa nao tem problrma, mas caso queira usar rotas?

Comment: Penso que relativamente ás rotas tens um certo número por dia

Comment: Pela resposta dada por @AndréRibeiro, é realmente isso. Porém o serviço pago, lendo a documentação faz entender que o custo é negociado, conforme o uso de certa quantidade e tipos de serviços. Não existe um custo "tabelado".